# Can a 17 year-old legally sign an International Employment Contract?

Tags: employment, australia, minor, philippines

I would like to know if a 17 year old is allowed to sign an International Employment Contract.

**Details:**
Employee is in the Philippines where it is legal for a 17 year old to work a full time job.
Employer is in Australia, New South Wales, where it is also legal for a 17 year old to work a full time job.

Is it legal to sign an International employment contract given those details? Would they also need a parent/guardian signature?

Comment: Can the Australian company abide by the laws/regulations of the Philippines? Is the 17 year old an actual employee, or a contractor? Does the Australian company have a nexus in the Philippines?

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is quite likely "yes". The 17 year old is allowed to sign. Other questions are: Are you allowed to sign a contract with a 17 year old? And: What happens if the 17 year old changes their mind or their legal guardian disagrees?